# How to use sockets to send information from javascript to python

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I want to send information from my Node.js code to Python using sockets. How can I achieve that?

In pseudo-code, what I want is this:

js:

```
sendInformation(information)
```

python:

```
recieveInformation()
sendNewInformation()
```

js:

```
recievNewInformation()
```

Comment: your pseudo code is very high level. Have you looked at basic socket tutorials and documentation for python and node?

Comment: I know how to do it in python, I can't figure out the node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should determine which code is the server and which one is the client. I assume your Python code is your server. 
You can run a server in python using:

```
import socket

HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 9999    

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(data)
```

And then you can connect your Nodejs client code to the server:

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 9999;

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
  console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
  // Write a message to the socket as soon as the client is connected, the server will receive it as message from the client
 client.write('Message from client');

});

// Add a 'data' event handler for the client socket
// data is what the server sent to this socket
client.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('DATA: ' + data);
  // Close the client socket completely
  client.destroy();
});

// Add a 'close' event handler for the client socket
client.on('close', function() {
  console.log('Connection closed');
});
```